# How to export or get a copy of the dictionary with the new words added there. I am using hunspell in terminal

Tags: linux, bash, fedora, hunspell

I have create a spanish dictionary or called private dictionary too, and the affix file which is a copy of es_EC.aff

```
echo -e '2\nWordPress\ne-commerce\n' > ~/.hunspell_default/es_GUAYACO.dic
cp /usr/share/hunspell/es_EC.aff ~/.hunspell_default/es_GUAYACO.aff
```

I have used this file to test.

```
cd ~/Downloads
echo 'hola wordPress E-commerce asesoria' > foo3.txt
hunspell -d es_GUAYACO foo3.txt
```

In the interactive mode:

- For the word `hola` , I selected `u` to add uncapitalized.
- `wordpress`, `u`
- `E` , `space`  to accept this time the word.
- `commerce` , `space`
- `asesoria`, `r` for replace, typed `asesoría` Enter, and `u`.

But the dictionary `es_GUAYACO.dic` was not updated, it doesn't have the words `hola, wordpress, asesoría`.

If we use other dictionary for example `en_US` is the same issue.

How can we export o get a copy of the dictionary with the new words added?

Answer (score 0):

All words is saved in a new file in the `$HOME` directory.

##### Hunspell used in the terminal

When you use any dictionary if you add new words using the letter `I` or `U`. Then a new files is created in `$HOME` directory. The file name is trailing the name of the dictionary used. e.g.

##### IN MY CASE

- .hunspell_en_US
- .hunspell_es_GUAYACO